# How to add CSS class dynamically to table row on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to highlight a row while I am on a specific row . I had to use onmouseover.

But it is not happening for me.

This is the table definition in cshtml.

```
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="severityCheck"><input type="checkbox" value="" /></th>
                                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                                            <th>Site Name</th>

                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach:CustomerList">
                                        <tr onclick="removepage();" onmouseover="changeRowColor(this)">

                                            <td>
                                                <input class="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { Id: 'checkbox' + $data.Id },click:$parent.customerClick" type="checkbox">

                                            </td>
                                            <td class="col-md-4">
                                                <span class="name" data-bind="text:customerName" />

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span data-bind="text:siteName" />
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

To highlight on mouseover , I wrote the changeRowColor as :

```
function changeRowColor(row) {
    row.addClass = 'active';

}
```

But the class is not being reflected. But when I do

```
row.style.backgroundColor= 'red';
```

it's happening.

What am I doing wrong ?

**Also , I have to highlight the current row only when the mouse is on top of this and not highlight when mouse leaves.**

How would I do that ?

Comment: have you tried to do this with :hover?

Comment: Is their a reason you're using JS for this and not CSS?

Comment: This has been answered a thousand times over on stackoverflow. Ive linked to one, you'll find a bunch more with a search.

Comment: I have to use Javascript. CSS I am not allowed to change.

Comment: `row.addClass('active');`

Answer (score 2):

why not use css

```
table tr:hover td{background-color:red;}
```

Comment: I have to use Javascript it seems. CSS I am not allowed to change.